# Android - Detect new direction (left/right) after every GPS update

Tags: java, android, gps

I need to calculate the new direction relative to the previous one at every GPS update by using coordinates. The only thing which is important here is left or right.

First I tried doing this by using the heading only, by just looking at the new heading if it was more to the west or east relative to the previous heading.
But after getting past 0 or 360 degrees point, problems occurred. This also did not seem like a very robust solution.

After 3 GPS updates there is always an array available of the latest 3 GPS coordinates.

The following coordinates should all show **left**, since it is on a roundabout:

```
58.70265614,12.45208851
58.70266725,12.45198338
58.7026786,12.4518954
58.70267177,12.45180805
58.70264375,12.45171462
58.70259777,12.45164779
58.70254734,12.45163389
58.7025029,12.45167082
58.70246575,12.45173065
58.70245399,12.45182545
58.7024728,12.45192582
58.70251695,12.45201489
58.70256638,12.45205355
58.70261456,12.45204386
58.70265059,12.45198956
58.70266192,12.45188943
```

I have difficulties looking at coordinates and see them as or convert them to Points or Vectors, and use this as the base to do calculations.
I did look into similar topics in C++ and C#, but I could not get it translated into my problem.

Also I don't need the complete solution. Pseudo code should be enough as long as the math is there. :)

Thank you for your time!